# set /p command is not working

Tags: batch-file

Well suddenly my set /p command doesn't seem to be responding. I have written

```
@echo off
set /p pass=
echo %pass%
pause
```

When I execute the above code the console displays, `ECHO is OFF`
without taking any input from the user.
I have recently used `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in some other program so has it anything to do with it

Comment: Can you try `!pass!`, instead of `%pass%` ?

Answer (score 2):

I've copy pasted your code and it is working for me (with and without `set ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`).
You did not indicate which version of windows you use.
try to change the set line to:

```
set /p pass=""
```

or to:

```
set /p pass="Enter your password:"
```

If it still not working for you, check if you can set the variable from a text file:

```
set /p pass=<filename.txt
```

Comment: I dont know what the problem was but as soon as I reopened my CMD everything seemed fine, but still thanks for your concern Luzon.......